# Non eager Kleene star in boost spirit qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I was trying to do the following to parse a number of "a", then one "a":

```
*(lit("a")) >> lit("a")
```

Unfortunately, the Kleene star `*` in boost::spirit::qi consumes all of the "a"s in an eager way, after which there is no backtracking, and the last `lit(a)` cannot match anything.

Of course, using (for example) `grep`, the following would work:

```
$ echo "aaa" | grep "a*a"
aaa
```

What is the best way to work around the behaviour of qi here? I understand that backtracking would mess up semantic actions, so let's assume that qi is only used to store attributes in an AST.

Using `+` instead of `*` would not solve my problem; suppose for example that I have a parser `ignore_int_` which parses integers but produces no attribute, then I might want to use:

`*ignore_int_ >> int_`

to store only the last integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only negatively assert things ahead of time:

```
 *(graph - 'z') >> 'z'
```

Here `graph` would match except when z is encountered. If you need this at the end of input/expression, think of e.g.

```
 *(graph - (graph >> eoi)) >> graph >> eoi
```

or

```
 *(!(graph >> eoi) >> graph) >> graph >> eoi
```

In short, you need a *positive* lookahead to "assert against". Implicit assertions won't get you the backtracking you expect, as Spirit is a PEG parser generator, not a Regular Expression matcher.